# TypeVar inference broken by lru_cache decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting, mypy, python-lru-cache

python's TypeVar inference broken when using lru_cache decorator. For example, after applying `mypy` the following example, only function with `lru_cache` causes error like:

```
main.py:14: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "T", variable has type "int")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

and pyright's editor support also warn the same thing. Is this `lru_cache`'s own limitation or is there some  good workaround?

```py
from functools import lru_cache
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def working(foo: T) -> T:
    return foo

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def not_working(foo: T) -> T:
    return foo

a: int = working(1)
b: int = not_working(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the relevant parts of the [`lru_cache` type hints](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/functools.pyi#L47)

```
_T = TypeVar("_T")

class _lru_cache_wrapper(Generic[_T]):
    __wrapped__: Callable[..., _T]
    def __call__(self, *args: Hashable, **kwargs: Hashable) -> _T: ...

def lru_cache(
    maxsize: int | None = ..., typed: bool = ...
) -> Callable[[Callable[..., _T]], _lru_cache_wrapper[_T]]: ...
```

so it appears that, in its attempts to allow for any argument set, it loses any connection between the input and output types and so is unable to refine `T` to `int`. You may have to wrap `lru_cache` locally to fix this. You may be able to use `ParamSpec`, but you might find difficulties with that, see the note below. If you only need it for a small set of function types (unary, binary, ternary), you could wrap it for those.

Apparently they did actually [fix this](https://github.com/python/typeshed/commit/8bda66a73725ff98919b8b57e600178591e948c2) with `ParamSpec` but from a cursory reading it appears to break other things so they [reverted it](https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/6356). [This issue](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/6347) also discusses it.